# how to include a parameter in strip payment gateway

Tags: php, strip

this is my code now i want to include plan=>monthly for recurring payment but its not taking plan=>monthly parameter and giving the error UNVALID REQ any other idea about recurring payment or please correct this one. Please

```
try{

require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');

Stripe::setApiKey("dfsdfsdfsd");

$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(

"amount" =>$amt,

"currency" => "usd",

"card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],

"description" => "asdasdad"



));
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use 'interval' parameter.

```
'interval' => 'month'
```

Comment: My bad, you should look for Plans or Subscriptions instead https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#create_plan